# Probability of number of people in car park at any given time

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A building has 22 car spaces, each having a car parked within each spot in the morning. Each car is retrieved by its respective owner at some point (random time) between 7am and 9am (120minutes). Each owner takes 5 minutes in the car park to pack the car, get in, and drive out.

At any random point in time, what is the probability that there are:

a) 0 people present in the car park

b) 1 person present in the car park

c) 2 people present in the car park

So far I'm looking at this as  binomial distribution, but I'm not sure I'm taking the right approach, or if there is a better way. With the binomial: n = 22 people, k = number of people present (ie 0, 1, 2), and $p = \frac{5}{120} = 0.041667$. So I'd get $a = 0.392, b = 0.375$, and $c = 0.171$...but just have a feeling I'm overlooking something major.

EDIT - Tried to clarify a little bit of the wording. The reasoning being that the question is trying to establish what the probability would be that, at some random time of query between 7am and 9am, of there being 0, 1 or 2 people present in the car park. The reason it deals with people and the 5 minute info, is this presents the opportunity for overlap, that multiple people may be retrieving their car at similar times. The 2-hour information defines the bounds from when the there are 22 cars to when there are zero.

Comment: The question is unclear. 1. Is all of this **per day**? 2. What is the relevance of the "Each car is retrieved by its respective owner over a 2 hour period" piece of information, if the question is only about the probability of people present in the car park?

Comment: Also, are you sure you're not asking about the number of **cars** present in the car park? That might explain a little bit on why we need the $5$-minute info and the $2$-hour info (assuming that each car is in the car park for $2$ hours and $5$ minutes per day).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S ince doors are opened  between 07.00 and 09.00 I'm assuming the arrival time $T$ of a particular owner is uniformly distributed in $[0,115]$. The probability $p_t$ that this owner is present at time $t\in[0,120]$ is then given by
$$p_t=\left\{\eqalign{ {\displaystyle{t\over115}}\qquad&(0\leq t\leq 5) \cr  
{\displaystyle{1\over23}}\qquad&(5\leq t\leq 115) \cr {\displaystyle{120-t\over115}}\quad&(115\leq t\leq120)\cr}\right.$$
The number $N_t$ of owners present at any given time $t$ is  binomially distributed, i.e. given by
$$P[N_t=k]={22\choose k}p_t^k\>(1-p_t)^{22-k}\ .$$

Comment: Since all the cars leave by $t=120$ the last driver must arrive by $t=115$ to allow for the 5 minutes it takes for them to leave. Therefore the arrival time of a driver in order to depart should be assumed uniforn on $[0,115] minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the drivers arrive at times uniformly distributed over $[0,120-5]$ minutes. At time $t\in [5,120]$ (no driver can leave before $t=5$) the probability that a given driver has left is $p(t)=\frac{t-5}{115}$.

Now the number who have left before $t>5$ is $n(t) \sim B(p(t),22)$, and the number remaining is $r(t)=22-n(t)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ denote the probability that any given person is present in the car park.

---

The probability that $0$ out of $22$ people are present in the car park is:

$$\binom{22}{0}\cdot(p^{0})\cdot(1-p)^{22-0}$$

The probability that $1$ out of $22$ people are present in the car park is:

$$\binom{22}{1}\cdot(p^{1})\cdot(1-p)^{22-1}$$

The probability that $2$ out of $22$ people are present in the car park is:

$$\binom{22}{2}\cdot(p^{2})\cdot(1-p)^{22-2}$$